# .htaccess: remove html extension, force www and https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I developed a simple and pure html site with this pages:

```
index.html
page1.html
page2.html
etc
```

And I would like to configure .htaccess to:

```
-Force https
-Force www
-Remove .html extension (/page1.html -> /page1)
-Redirect index.html -> /
-When someone types /page1.html to be redirected to /page1 (without html) or (if not possible) to 404 error page
```

How should I configure my .htaccess?

Thanks in advance

Comment: All those questions have been answered here on SO hundreds, if not thousands of times. None of all those answers helped you to get starting? Tell us: _why_ did all those answers not get you going and why should an additional answer make a difference?

Comment: Yes, I am able to find here how to force https and www.But I'm not able to find how can I remove "html" extension when some one types page.html in browser.

Comment: Then I suggest you start with those two aspects, then post the dynamic configuration file you have so far and explain why you attempts to solve that remaining issue does not work. There are endless answers for that too, so assuming you looked around a bit there has to be some issue with your attempt. But we cannot help with that before you post your code, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove .html and to force https://www , you can use the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on
#force https+www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%1/$1 [NE,L,R]
#Remove .html
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.html [L]
```

Clear your browser cache before testing these rules.

Comment: Worked fine! +1 and +1 beer!! So happy!

Answer (score 0):

```
#OK we force https and www
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.exmple.com/$1 [L,R=301]

#  remove .html from uri
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

# remove trailing slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# redirect index.html -> /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.html$
Redirect /index.html /
```

All seems to work except when I enter example.com/page1.html. It doesn't remove html